# Sharing Application.conf between backend and frontend

Tags: angularjs, scala, user-interface, typesafe

I am working on an webApp whose backend is in Scala and frontend is in Angularjs, backend configuration is driven by `application.conf`, which contains all info of services, host and port configuration.

The current implementation of frontend takes the config from `applicaton.conf` in a manner

```
echo "xstream {
     service {
       host = 0.0.0.0
       port = 9090
       SSL = false
       yarnPort = 8088
       metricsPort = 8082
     }

" > assets/json/application.conf
```

via network call, which exposes the `application.conf` in the network call.

I am looking for the solution where the single `application.conf` can be shared between the frontend and backend without, `application.conf` being exposed in the network call as that would lead to risk of sharing sensitive info.

Comment: Anything you send to the front-end is at risk of being exposed. Anyone with devtools (which is everyone) can see the results of all network calls.

Comment: what is appropriate method ?

Comment: The appropriate method to have sensitive data in the front-end? There isn't one. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems that you are sending data from the server to the web application on an unencrypted channel. This is a bad idea for all sorts of reasons, so you should really consider fixing that first. Worrying about the security of the `Application.conf` seems a minor issue compared to all the other data you are going to be exposing on the wire.

If you absolutely have to use an insecure channel, then there are two options open:

1. Implement your own encryption within the data on that channel
2. Create a second secure channel for passing the sensitive data

For the first option there are a number of Scala encryption libraries to choose from.

For the second option you can (theoretically) create a separate TLS connection using an SSL library without the server certificate checking (which is, I presume, the reason for not using `https` in the first place)

Stackoverflow is not the place to ask for recommendations, so you need to do your own research to find suitable libraries for whichever option you choose.